# remove a class if already exists by using toggleClass

Tags: jquery

How to remove a class if already exists by using toggleClass

```
$('.mobile_billing').toggleClass('open');
```

I've a scenario where we use above code to expand and collapse the accordion. There are two options to collapse and expand:

1. From Accordion arrow
2. From Check BOX.

When user clicks on Check Box and Accordion is already expanded No action is required. Where as if Accordion is in Collpase state, would like to open it.

I tried above code, it either opens or close. It doesn't check if already open. Can someone please help

Comment: We'd need more code to catch your bug. A `this` is probably missing...

Comment: try using another attribute such as `rel` and change its value to collapsed or expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write two seperate events for checkbox and accordian

suppose checkbox `id=checkbox`

```
$("#checkbox").click(function(){      
   if(!$('.mobile_billing').hasClass('open')) // it checks if mobile_billing is not open
     $('.mobile_billing').addClass('open');
});
```

And 
suppose accordian has `id=accordian`

```
 $("#accordian").click(function(){

         $('.mobile_billing').addClass('open');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When `click on the checkbox`  check for the Accordion is open or not if if is in open state `return` from the `function`. otherwise do toggle action.

```
$('#checkboxId').on('click',function(){
  if($('.mobile_billing').hasClass('open')) return;

  $('.mobile_billing').toggleClass('open');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$( '.accordion_checkbox' ).click( function() { 
  $( '.mobile_billing' ).toggleClass( 'open', this.checked );
});
```

So 'open' only gets added when the checkbox is checked and removed when it's unchecked by the user. It's irrelevant whether it's open already when the user clicks on the checkbox; it'll just stay open. This is using [jQuery.toggleClass's switch option](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-switch) and checking the [checked (boolean) value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426276/1203825) of the checkbox you've attached the click event to.